# How to point or reference a dynamically created item

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm working on an invoice system. I need to add the invoice item dynamically by **addchild** method as below mentioned

1.select product(combo box)-- Quandity(text box)--Price(text box)--***Total(text box)***

2.select product(combo box)-- Quandity(text box)--Price(text box)--***Total(text box)***

My problem is i cant bring the sum amount of all the ***Total text boxes*** of each child element..

***How to point or refernece a dynamically created item????***

Answer (score 1):

You can store all created item in a Array (or Vector), and then access each of them thru a cycle.

For example:

```
var allPrices:Array = [15.50, 20.24, 36.12];

var allElements:Array = new Array();

for (price in prices) {

      // PriceText class is, for example, a movieclip with a textbox inside
      var obj:PriceText = new PriceText(price);

      addChild(obj);

      allElements.push(obj);

}
```

Now you have all added elements in the `allElements` array.

Answer (score 1):

Or You can create reference object , like :

```
class Bind {
   public var target:Object;
   public var key:String;

   public function Bind(t:Object , k:String){
      target = t;
      key = k;
   }
   public function get value():* {
      return target[key];
   }
}

var myItem:SomeClass;
myItem.param = 100;
var bind:Bind = new Bind(myItem,"param");

trace("get myItem value:", bind.value);
```